# List of figures, Change caption name

Tags: table-of-contents, captions

I'm trying to make a list of figures but am having some problems with the captioning.

Some pictures have long names since I explain some things in the caption, but I don't want this to show in the list of figures. How can I change it?

Attached a picture of how it looks right now. I want it only to read "2.6 Proportional control" as an example.

[image]

Comment: try `\caption[short]{very very long}`

Comment: ...different float, same solution...

Answer (score 9):

The `\caption` command also has an optional parameter, `\caption[''short'']{''long''}` which is used for the List of Tables or List of Figures.

Typically the short description is for the caption listing, and the long description will be placed beside the figure or table. This is particularly useful if the caption is long, and only a "one-liner" is desired in the figure/table listing.

Here is an example of this usage:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption[Image A]{Image A : describe it here.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering
      \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption[Image B]{Image B : describe it here.}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Hope this helps. You can find more about `\caption` [here.](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions)